# What is the fastest collection type python has when you know where the data is in the collection?

Tags: python, dataframe, collections

I need to loop through datasets(10000 records each) of equal data size and structure and pull data from various points in the datasets depending on user input.  I then make calculations on that data across the datasets and continue looping. The calculations are complex and involve multiple datasets(looping through all at the same time) Given the user input, combined with data from the row I am on, I know where in the datasets I need to pull from to assist in the calculations IE

```
x = list[4][3]
```

Currently I am iterating over dataframes and if information in the row matches user criteria, I loop through and perform calculations stored in a list of classes. Those calculations involve pulling data from known points in the dataframes using iloc.

I have tested the iterating loop of the dataframe using iterrows, itertuples and i in df.index and found df.index to be fastest.

I can switch all collections to something like a multidimentional list(even the list of classes) as there is no required searching of any collection due to knowing the exact points in the collections the data is given calculations. I believe I have done as much vectorization on data as I can at this point.

Currently, depending on user input, this can take over an hour so I need to optimize where I can.

Before I do this(its an undertaking) I was wondering what is the fastest collection to loop through and pull known points of data from in python? It can be immutable. I am leaning towards multidimentional lists. Am I incorrect?

EDIT:

Here is one of the main loop functions:

```
def runOnce(self,calcIterations):
        try:
            #create dataframe and dictionary
            columnNames = ["Decision Date"]
            for stock in GU.stockList:
                columnNames.append(stock.name + " price")
                columnNames.append(stock.name + " % from MA")
            columnNames.append("Trade Date")
            columnNames.append("TDate Value")
            columnNames.append("MOVEMENT")
            outdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = columnNames)

            #loop over each day
            totalDays = len(GU.stockList[0].df)
            monthCount = 0
            createData = True
            if len(calcIterations) > 1:
                #do not create daily data if doing more than one run
                createData = False

            for i in GU.stockList[0].df.index:

                #check if all dates on that day are equal
                iDate = GU.stockList[0].df.iloc[i]['Date']

                #dates are equal
                #check if next date is a new month as calculations only happen on that day
                if(i+1 == totalDays):
                    break
                if(iDate.month != GU.stockList[0].df.iloc[i-1]['Date'].month):
                    #new month
                    monthCount += 1
                    #loop through the iterations doing the calculations
                    for ci in calcIterations:
                        if(monthCount % int(ci.cycle) != 0):
                            #not right month cycle, no calculations
                            continue
                        if ci.trade+i >= totalDays:
                            #not enough data for this ci
                            continue
                        #time for calculations
                        #do percent difference
                        lStock = GU.stockList[0]
                        lStock.percentFromMA = 10000
                        outRow = [str(lStock.df.iloc[i+ci.decision]['Date'].date())] #Decision date
                        for stock in GU.stockList:
                            c = stock.df.iloc[i+ci.decision]['Close']
                            outRow.append(c) #close value
                            ma = Decimal(stock.df.iloc[i+ci.decision]['MA' + str(ci.ma)])
                            #calculate percent difference
                            stock.percentFromMA = (c / ma - 1) * 100

                            outRow.append(stock.percentFromMA) #percentfrom MA
                            #grab lowest stock
                            if stock.percentFromMA < lStock.percentFromMA:
                                lStock = stock
                        #percent difference is complete, do the sell and buy   '{0:.2f}'.format(pi)
                        outRow.append(str(lStock.df.iloc[i+ci.trade]['Date'].date())) #trade date
                        buySharePrice = (lStock.df.iloc[i+ci.trade]['High'] + lStock.df.iloc[i+ci.trade]['Low']) / Decimal(2)
                        comments = ""
                        sStock = lStock
                        if lStock.name == ci.stockName:
                            #same stock do nothing
                            outRow.append(ci.shareNum * buySharePrice + ci.residule)
                            outRow.append("Same stock no change")
                            if len(calcIterations) == 1:
                                #only 1 run so do csv dataframe
                                outdf = outdf.append(pd.Series(outRow,index=outdf.columns),ignore_index=True)
                            continue
                        if ci.shareNum != 0:
                            #sell before buying
                            #get current stock and trading price
                            for stock in GU.stockList:
                                if ci.stockName == stock.name:
                                    sStock = stock
                            sellSharePrice = (sStock.df.iloc[i+ci.trade]['High'] + sStock.df.iloc[i+ci.trade]['Low']) / Decimal(2)
                            ci.currentAmount = sellSharePrice * ci.shareNum + ci.residule
                            ci.currentAmount = ci.currentAmount - ci.fees
                            ci.feesPaid = ci.feesPaid + ci.fees
                            comments += "Sold " + sStock.name + ":" + str(ci.shareNum) + " shares at $" + str(sellSharePrice) + " and $" + str(ci.residule) + " residue : "
                        #buy stock at trade price
                        ci.currentAmount = ci.currentAmount - ci.fees
                        ci.feesPaid = ci.feesPaid + ci.fees
                        ci.shareNum = int(ci.currentAmount / buySharePrice)
                        ci.residule = ci.currentAmount - (ci.shareNum * buySharePrice)
                        ci.stockName = lStock.name
                        outRow.append(ci.currentAmount) #current worth on trade day
                        comments += "Purchased " + lStock.name + ":" + str(ci.shareNum) + " shares at $" + str(buySharePrice) + " and $" + str(ci.residule) + " residue."
                        outRow.append(comments) #movement
                        if len(calcIterations) == 1:
                            #only 1 run so do csv dataframe
                            outdf = outdf.append(pd.Series(outRow,index=outdf.columns),ignore_index=True)
            if len(calcIterations) == 1:
                #print the csv
                outdf.to_csv("OneRun.csv", index=False)
        except Exception:
            raise
```

EDIT2:
Also if it helps here is a profile of a short run of that function

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   320477   53.627    0.000  134.463    0.000 managers.py:878(fast_xs)
 33971951   22.461    0.000   28.917    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
   640954   16.092    0.000   20.291    0.000 numerictypes.py:578(_can_coerce_all)
  3204912    7.762    0.000   10.305    0.000 common.py:1886(_is_dtype_type)
320482/320481    7.536    0.000  110.313    0.000 series.py:197(__init__)
  2884386    7.115    0.000   12.014    0.000 common.py:1743(is_extension_array_dtype)
   320496    6.162    0.000   61.699    0.000 construction.py:630(sanitize_array)
  1281919    5.521    0.000   15.087    0.000 common.py:1619(is_bool_dtype)
        1    5.339    5.339  291.905  291.905 FTATool.py:107(runOnce)
   320477    5.298    0.000  254.900    0.001 frame.py:2916(_ixs)
   320496    5.190    0.000   42.226    0.000 construction.py:759(_try_cast)
12837927/10915015    5.135    0.000    6.070    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the Pandas/DataFrame code? Or the entire program, for that matter, we're going to need a good amount of information on this specific situation.

Comment: Pandas is probably the fastest, but only if you use its built-in series operations. If you write your own loops, you're not going to get optimal code.

Comment: If you know the indices, extracting data from a list is constant time. But you may want to provide a minimal example of the DataFrame and show how you are searching, someone may have a better way.  Have you considered a database and queiries?

Comment: I posted code and profiler snapshot.

Comment: You should definitely *not* be using pandas like this. It is going to end up being way more inefficient that using built-in data structures.

Comment: I agree hence my question. I had used pandas to start thinking I could use vectorization etc but cannot make it go